# Conditional assign in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Assume I have `df` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
    'V': np.array(range(0,10))
})
```

I want to `groupby` the `ID` variable and assign values to a new column `X` depending on (1) the size of each group and whether each row is the top (`T`), "middle" (more like in between top and bottom) (`M`) or bottom (`B`) row. If there's only one row in a group the value assigned is `N`. In this case the result would look like:

```
    ID  V   X
0   a   0   N
1   b   1   T
2   b   2   B
3   c   3   T
4   c   4   M
5   c   5   B
6   d   6   T
7   d   7   M
8   d   8   M
9   d   9   B
```

I can do this step-wise using something like (for the `T` case):

```
df.join(df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).groupby('ID').head(1).assign(X='T').X, how='left')
```

But this feels like a bad solution. I'd rather do it all in one go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is straightforward from your logic:

```
groups = df.groupby('ID')
first = groups['V'].head(1).index
last = groups['V'].tail(1).index

# the default middle values
df['X'] = 'M'

# the top and bottom values
df.loc[first, 'X'] = 'T'
df.loc[last, 'X'] = 'B'

# the unique values
ones = groups['V'].transform('size') == 1
df.loc[ones, 'X'] = 'N'
```

Output:

```
  ID  V  X
0  a  0  N
1  b  1  T
2  b  2  B
3  c  3  T
4  c  4  M
5  c  5  B
6  d  6  T
7  d  7  M
8  d  8  M
9  d  9  B
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this would be to compare the ID of each row with the ID before / after it.

For example:

```
df["top"] = df.ID != df.shift().ID
df["bottom"] = df.ID != df.shift(-1).ID
df["mid"] = (df.ID == df.shift(-1).ID) & (df.ID == df.shift(1).ID)
```

This results in:

```
    ID  V   bottom  top mid
0   a   0   True    True    False
1   b   1   False   True    False
2   b   2   True    False   False
3   c   3   False   True    False
4   c   4   False   False   True
5   c   5   True    False   False
6   d   6   False   True    False
7   d   7   False   False   True
8   d   8   False   False   True
9   d   9   True    False   False
```

You can now use whatever logic you want to create the T/B/M/N column:

```
df.loc[df.bottom & (~df.mid), "V"] = "B"
df.loc[df.top & (~df.mid), "V"] = "T"
df.loc[df.mid, "V"] = "M"
df.loc[df.bottom & df.top, "V"] = "N"

df[["ID", "V"]]
```

results in:

```
    ID  V
0   a   N
1   b   T
2   b   B
3   c   T
4   c   M
5   c   B
6   d   T
7   d   M
8   d   M
9   d   B
```